# How To Tell weblogic To Not Log Certain Requests In Its Access Log?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, access-log

I have all the requests going to access.log in weblogic server, I need to stop logging few request patterns. Is there any possibility ?

I already customized the access loggers with CustomELFLogger and seems to be there is no option to stop the logs not to go to access.log file.

Any other thoughts ?

Comment: You can stop logging all requests for a particular web app but not filter them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature to filter the particular requests but a workaround would be , implement the customelflogger and replace cs-uri filed with custom class.

In the custom class, just put a condition for the specific requests that needs to be filtered and leave the rest.

It is working as expected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17267768)

Comment: Well I'm the owner of the post :)